# Two UI pickers in the same view controller Objective C?

Tags: ios, uipicker

So ive got my UI picker but it is displaying the same data for each of the UI pickers but i would like it to display the moustache array in one ui picker and the colour one in the other. Currently shown in the image it is assigning the same data to each array.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _colourSourceArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"No Frame",@"Red", @"Green", @"Blue", @"Black",@"Yellow", nil ];
    _MustacheArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"None",@"Pencil",@"The Professor",@"The Regent",@"Hipster",@"Super Mario", nil];

    [_picker selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
    [_notcolourpicker selectRow:1 inComponent:0 animated:YES];

    _picker.tag=0;
    _notcolourpicker.tag=1;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView: (UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    switch (component) {
        case 0:
            return _colourSourceArray.count;
            break;
        case 1:
            return _MustacheArray.count;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return  0;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    switch (component) {
        case 0:
            return [_colourSourceArray objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        case 1:
            return [_MustacheArray objectAtIndex:row];
        default:
            break;
    }

    return  0;
}

-(IBAction)returnToExportSettingsVC:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    // Nothing needed here.
}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (component == 0) {
        NSLog(@"First");

        NSString *s = _colourSourceArray[row];

        _selectedcolour = s;
        NSLog(_selectedcolour);
    }
    else
        if(component == 1){
            NSLog(@"Second");
            NSString *d = _MustacheArray[row];

            _selectedmustache=d;

            NSLog(_selectedmustache);
        }

    /// Used if you wist to assign the selected row to a label to show a users selection.
    //_label.text=  [_MustacheArray objectAtIndex:[mostachepicker selectedRowInComponent:1]];
}
```

[image]

Comment: Just add a `tag` to the picker view in your storyboard and then when returning the data from the data source check which picker is requesting the data by doing `if picker.tag == 1 { ... } else if picker.tag == 2 { ... }`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that both picker views are calling into the same data source / delegate methods. If you're doing to structure your code that way, you will need to examine the `pickerView` parameter to see *which* picker view this is, and switch on that.