# Swift conflicting UIPickerView

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I have been trying to figure out why the picker views are sending conflicting results to my functions. When I change one picker view it overwrites the value set by the previous picker view selected. the commonality between pickerviews is they are populated they are populated with the same array. Below is the code that controls the pickerviews and a screen shot of the form. When the top lender is selected first and the bottom lender is selected last the formula uses the bottom lender for the calculation. But if I reverse the order by selecting the bottom lender first then the top lender it calculates using the top lender. The same error happens when selecting the value with 60 in it. the last value selected sets the value passed to the formulas. Each selected value needs to keep its own selected value

[image]

```
 func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    if pickerView == currentLenderPicker
        {
            return newLender[row]
    }
    else if pickerView == newLenderPicker
    {
        return newLender[row]
    }
    else if pickerView == currentPaymentFrequencyPicker
    {
        return paymentFrequency[row]
    }
    else if pickerView == newPaymentFrequencyPicker
    {
        return paymentFrequency[row]
    }
    else if pickerView == mortgageTermPicker
    {
        return mortgageTerm[row]
    }
    else if pickerView == newMortgageTermPicker
    {
        return mortgageTerm[row]
    }
    return ""

}


func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    if pickerView == currentLenderPicker
        {
            return lenders.count
    }
    else if pickerView == newLenderPicker
    {
        return newLender.count
    }
    else if pickerView == currentPaymentFrequencyPicker
    {
        return paymentFrequency.count
    }
    else if pickerView == newPaymentFrequencyPicker
    {
        return paymentFrequency.count
    }
    else if pickerView == mortgageTermPicker
    {
        return mortgageTerm.count
    }
    else if pickerView == newMortgageTermPicker
    {
        return mortgageTerm.count
    }
    return 1
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {


    return 1
}

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        if pickerView == currentLenderPicker
        {
            orginalLender.text = lenders[row]

        }
        else if pickerView == newLenderPicker
        {
            newMortgageLender.text = newLender[row]

        }
        else if pickerView == currentPaymentFrequencyPicker
        {
            currentPaymentFrequency.text = paymentFrequency[row]
        }
        else if pickerView == newPaymentFrequencyPicker
        {
            newPaymentFrequency.text = paymentFrequency[row]
        }

        else if pickerView == mortgageTermPicker
        {
            currentMortgageTerm.text = mortgageTerm[row]
        }
        else if pickerView == newMortgageTermPicker
        {
            newMortgageTerm.text = mortgageTerm[row]
        }

        if let selectedLender = currentLender.filter({ $0.fiName == lenders[row] }).first {
            Global.selectedRate = selectedLender
        }

        self.view.endEditing(false)
}
```

I made the changes using tags but I am still having the same issue. Updated code below.

```
    // Load FI Information

   func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    if pickerView.tag == 1
        {
            return newLender[row]
    }
    else if pickerView.tag == 11
    {
        return newLender[row]
    }
    else if pickerView.tag == 10
    {
        return paymentFrequency[row]
    }
    else if pickerView.tag == 15
    {
        return paymentFrequency[row]
    }
    else if pickerView.tag == 6
    {
        return mortgageTerm[row]
    }
    else if pickerView.tag == 17
    {
        return mortgageTerm[row]
    }
    return ""

}


func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    if pickerView.tag == 1
        {
            return lenders.count
    }
    else if pickerView.tag == 11
    {
        return newLender.count
    }
    else if pickerView.tag == 10
    {
        return paymentFrequency.count
    }
    else if pickerView.tag == 15
    {
        return paymentFrequency.count
    }
    else if pickerView.tag == 6
    {
        return mortgageTerm.count
    }
    else if pickerView.tag == 17
    {
        return mortgageTerm.count
    }
    return 1
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {


    return 1
}

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        if pickerView.tag == 1
        {
            orginalLender.text = lenders[row]

        }
        else if pickerView.tag == 11
        {
            newMortgageLender.text = newLender[row]

        }
        else if pickerView.tag == 10
        {
            currentPaymentFrequency.text = paymentFrequency[row]
        }
        else if pickerView.tag == 15
        {
            newPaymentFrequency.text = paymentFrequency[row]
        }

        else if pickerView.tag == 6
        {
            currentMortgageTerm.text = mortgageTerm[row]
        }
        else if pickerView.tag == 17
        {
            newMortgageTerm.text = mortgageTerm[row]
        }

        if let selectedLender = currentLender.filter({ $0.fiName == lenders[row] }).first {
            Global.selectedRate = selectedLender
        }

        self.view.endEditing(false)
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two UI pickers in the same view controller Objective C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38414185/two-ui-pickers-in-the-same-view-controller-objective-c)

Comment: every time you select a row you execture the if let selectLender code. Is this performing the correct logic? where is currentLender being set?

Answer (score 1):

You should use tag for indicating specific pickerView. Check this answer & it will clear things up

[Implement PickerView With Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39243954/5980454)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I switched to using tags and  the same issue occurs.